# How to find dynamic value from string without using substring and indexOf

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

I have string which contains dynamic values. I want to find this index of array from the string without using `substring` or `indexOf`.

```
"XPath /package/items/item[**123**]/name"
```

Consider that instead of 123 there will be any values.

Comment: use regex with match method

Comment: @PranavCBalan: can you what will be the syntex of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "XPath /package/items/item[**123**]/name";
str.match(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/)[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

You will want to use regular expressions to accomplish this. Refer to [this resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) from Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: This is not an answer... Should be posted as comment.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Got it; I will keep this in mind with future answers. Thanks.